# Hibernate -- Mapping a view with a single value to a read-only field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, view

(Hibernate 3.6, Mysql 5)

I have a mapped class called 'Program' (that is working correctly).

I also have a view that is updated daily with aggregate statistics.

The view schema is like so:

```
view ProgramSummary {
     long program_id
     long value
}
```

program_id is unique, but there is no row-id. What I want is to just pull the value out, but I can't seem to figure out the right semantics.

I have tried mapping a separate entitiy with a OneToOne (and ManyToOne) relationship, but it gets confused between the ids. Without marking program_id as an entity, hibernate can't handle the actual mapping.

Is there a simple way to do this? It is a read-only field that is accessed by an external process and I don't have any leeway for changing the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula in your Program hbm file to map this.

```
<property name="SummaryValue" type="long" formula="(SELECT value FROM ProgramSummary WHERE ProgramSummary.program_id = id)" />
```

Assuming your field is named SummaryValue this line will update that field in the Program object.  Any field mapped with a formula is not updateable.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Sorry it took so long to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you map a second entity, you might want to set the columns to `updatable=false` and `insertable=false`, making them readonly.

However, why don't you just select the value from ProgramSummary, probably with plain SQL?